# How Can I read a file using sharpsvn client using c#

Tags: c#, sharpsvn

Is there any way to read a file using sharpsvn................

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want [SvnClient.Write](http://docs.sharpsvn.net/current/html/M_SharpSvn_SvnClient_Write_1.htm)()... This allows writing specific versions of a file to a stream.

Comment: hi Bert Huijben, thanks for ur ans..........

Although I can write a file in sharpsvn using svnclient.write(). If the file contains more than 1 revisions. how can I write those revisioned file contents separately ......

Comment: @Prabu: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425732/how-to-read-each-revision-of-file-using-sharpsvn-client-using-c